# RiverPod StateNotifierProvider causing causing "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build"

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In my app I am trying to a notifications indicator in the app bar. To do this I am using RiverPod's StateNotifierProvider and followed their documentation for v2 to set it up.

Here is my code for this notifier:

```
class NotificationNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<UserNotification>> {
  NotificationNotifier() : super([]);

  List<UserNotification> get getState => state;

  Future<List<UserNotification>> fetchUserNotifications(uid) async {
    state = [];
    try {
      final res = await http.get(Uri.parse("${Environment().config.baseApiUrl}/users/$uid/notifications"));
      final data = jsonDecode(res.body);
      List<UserNotification> retrievedNotifications = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data["notifications"].length; i++) {
        UserNotification tmpNotifications = UserNotification.fromJson(data["notifications"][i]);
        retrievedNotifications.add(tmpNotifications);
      }
      state = [...state, ...retrievedNotifications];

      print("fetchUserNotifications:state: $state");

      return state;
    } catch (err) {
      throw Exception("Unable to fetch user notifications: $err");
    }
  }

  Future<int> onClickNotification(UserNotification notification) async {
    print("UserRepositoryNotifier:onClickNotification");

    for (var n = 0; n < state.length; n++) {
      if (state[n].notificationId == notification.notificationId) {
        try {
          final response = await http.patch(
            Uri.parse("${Environment().config.baseApiUrl}/notifications/${state[n].notificationId}"),
          );

          return response.statusCode;
        } catch (err) {
          throw Exception("Unable to fetch user frieds: $err");
        }
      }
    }

    return 1;
  }
}
```

To keep the icon in the app bar updated I need to call `fetchUserNotifications`, which I've tried to do in `initState`, `didChangeDependencies`, and `build`. However, since it sets the `state` property with `state = [...state, ...retrievedNotifications];` it triggers a rebuild which causes Flutter to complain with this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this since I think I need to set the state property for this to work. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding how this all comes together?

Comment: The problem likely isn't in the code you shared, but rather your widget.

Comment: `... called during build` so.... we needa see the build method.